# jsp in a html frameset not compiled : weblogic

Tags: jsp, weblogic, frameset

I have this simple code :

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Properties"%>
<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Vijay's TEst</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="17%,*">
<frame name="header" src="test_headers.jsp" scrolling="no" noresize frameborder="0" />
</frameset>
</html>
```

But the problem is I get a Error 404--Not Found when I compile & run this jsp in weblogic.

Please help me with this.

Comment: do you have a test_headers.jsp file? Can you try running that directly?

Comment: <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test_style.jsp" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="thePage">
        <table width="100%" style="{border: thin solid;}">
        <tr><td>
                <table width="100%" border="0";>
                <tr><td><h3>MY Tests</h3></td>
                        <td style="{text-align: right;}"><img src="/MEDIA/logo.gif" alt="my logo" border="0" /></td></tr>
                </table>
        </td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>

Comment: Did you run it? from the browser?

Comment: yes Jose.. i run it from the browser.

Comment: there are no issues with the main  jsp compilation...but somehow the jsp mentioned in the <frame src="test_headers.jsp"..> is not picked up & i get Error 404-not found.

Comment: okay, are main.jsp and test_headers.jsp in the same folder?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say the jsp which is run is **Test.jsp** .

Location of **Test.jsp** -- WebContent

Location of **test_headers.jsp** -- WebContent

Then this is valid.

```
<frame name="header" src="test_headers.jsp" scrolling="no" />
```

Location of **Test.jsp** -- WebContent

Location of **test_headers.jsp** -- WebContent/jsp

Then this is valid

```
<frame name="header" src="/jsp/test_headers.jsp" scrolling="no" />
```